# An expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected - on INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age, measurement.*, ssf.*
from 
    Admin.Table_Study as study
INNER JOIN 
    (Admin.Table_Data as measurement
INNER JOIN
    Admin.Table_ComboBox as ssf)
ON
    study.UID = ssf.UID
where
    measurement.IsMeasurement = 1
```

I am trying to get the Data from multiple tables using INNER JOIN. I tried multiple solutions but couldn't get to the root cause.

P.S: Admin.Table_Study and Admin.Table_ComboBox has a PK FK relation over UID.

Comment: Why those brackets? Each JOIN wants an ON.

Comment: `INNER JOIN  (Admin.Table_Data as measurement` has no `ON` clause (and the odd parenthesis).

Comment: Admin.Table_Data dont have any connection with any of the other table thats why i skipped ON.  
What should i do in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Admin.Table_Data dont have any connection with any of the other table thats why i skipped ON. What should i do in that case?

It sounds like what you want is a *cross join*. That is also known as a cartesian join (but that's not what SQL chose to name it) where you join *every* row from the left table to *every* row from the right table:

```
SELECT 
    study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age, measurement.*, ssf.*
from 
    Admin.Table_Study as study
CROSS JOIN 
    Admin.Table_Data as measurement
INNER JOIN
    Admin.Table_ComboBox as ssf
ON
    study.UID = ssf.UID
where
    measurement.IsMeasurement = 1
```

Because it's `all <=> all`, `CROSS JOIN` doesn't have an `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the update it seems more "according to the need". It works exactly what i want. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the `INNER JOIN` has no `(`..`)` parenthesis & it has one `ON` clause :

For instance you have two `INNER JOIN`s, but only one `ON` clause, so remaining `JOIN`s expecting `ON` clause :

```
SELECT study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age, measurement.*, ssf.*
FROM [Admin].Table_Study AS study INNER JOIN 
     [Admin].Table_Data AS measurement
     ON measurement.col = study.col INNER JOIN
     [Admin].Table_ComboBox AS ssf
     ON study.UID = ssf.UID;
```

**EDIT :** If `[Admin].Table_Data` has no connection with other tables you can use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age
FROM [Admin].Table_Study AS study INNER JOIN
     [Admin].Table_ComboBox AS ssf
     ON study.UID = ssf.UID;
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL,  NULL, NULL,  NULL, COL1, COL2
FROM [Admin].Table_Data AS td
```

Comment: [Admin].Table_Data dont have any connection with any of the other table thats why i skipped ON.
What do you suggest me to do in that case?

Comment: @Mirza. . . Use `UNION ALL` instead of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

An `INNER JOIN` need an `ON`, need a condition to join

```
SELECT 
    study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age, measurement.*, ssf.*
from 
    Admin.Table_Study as study INNER JOIN Admin.Table_Data as measurement
      ON study.ID = measurement.ID -- that what  you miss
    INNER JOIN Admin.Table_ComboBox as ssf
      ON study.UID = ssf.UID
where
    measurement.IsMeasurement = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query the way to join study and SSF is defined. But how to join measurement and ssf is not defined.
Also, you do not define how to join the measurement.

You could greatly simplify this query if you write it like below, but you will need to specify the join conditions that are missing:

```
SELECT 
    study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age, measurement.*, ssf.*
from 
    Admin.Table_Study as study

INNER JOIN 
    Admin.Table_Data as measurement
ON *********************    

INNER JOIN
    Admin.Table_ComboBox as ssf
ON
    study.UID = ssf.UID

where
    measurement.IsMeasurement = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this expression. in Sql-server no need of giving () in joins.

```
SELECT 
    study.Name, study.Type, study.Weight, study.Height, study.Age, measurement.*, ssf.*
from 
    Admin.Table_Study as study
INNER JOIN 
    Admin.Table_Data as measurement
ON 
    study.ID = measurement.ID   --******this is what you missed
INNER JOIN
    Admin.Table_ComboBox as ssf
ON
    study.UID = ssf.UID
where
    measurement.IsMeasurement = 1
```

Comment: You just copy the code from my answer and add extra `*****` to it

Comment: I have not seen your code also. i gave my own reply.